# How to change TextBlock's background color if string values are unequal?

Tags: c#, wpf, binding

I have a UserControl that exists of only two TextBlocks:

```
<UserControl [...] x:Name="root">
    <StackPanel Orientation="Vertical">
        <TextBlock Text="{Binding Text1, ElementName=root}" /> 
        <TextBlock Text="{Binding Text2, ElementName=root}" />
    </StackPanel> 
</UserControl>
```

The corresponding code-behind looks like this:

```
public static readonly DependencyProperty Text1Property = DependencyProperty.Register("Text1", typeof(String), typeof(CmpText)); 
public static readonly DependencyProperty Text2Property = DependencyProperty.Register("Text2", typeof(String), typeof(CmpText)); 

public string Text1 
{ 
    get { return (string)GetValue(Text1Property); } 
    set { SetValue(Text1Property, value); } 
} 

public string Text2 
{ 
    get { return (string)GetValue(Text2Property); } 
    set { SetValue(Text2Property, value); } 
}
```

And this is how I use this UserControl in MainWindow.xml:

```
<local:CmpText Text1="{Binding Password1}" Text2="{Binding Password2}" />
```

What I basically want is the second TextBlock's background to change its color to red if both Text1 and Text2 are unequal.

I tried to use a helper property in the code-behind:

```
public bool IsEqual { get { return Text1 == Text2; } }
```

And set the second TextBlock's Style to

```
<Style TargetType="{x:Type TextBlock}"> 
     <Style.Triggers> 
         <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding IsEqual, ElementName=root}" Value="True"> 
             <Setter Property="Background" Value="Red"/> 
         </DataTrigger> 
     </Style.Triggers> 
 </Style>
```

However, IsEqual always turns out to be 'true' (and the TextBlock's background is always red) even if the Text1 & Text2 properties don't match. I think my helper property 'IsEqual' compares the default values of Text1 & Text2, which happen to be NULL (I don't have any way to confirm that, since I cannot debug the GUI). So the evaluation of IsEqual seems to happen before my text properties get assigned any values. I want the evaluation to happen *after* the text properties get assigned.

I don't know how to proceed. Can you help?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Currently there is no way that WPF could find out that `IsEqual` has changed, so the binding won't be re-evaluated.

You could do three things:

1. Make `IsEqual` another dependency property and add [PropertyChangedCallback](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.propertychangedcallback.aspx)s to the `Text1` and `Text2` which, whenever they change, update `IsEqual`.
2. Or, implement [INotifyPropertyChanged](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.inotifypropertychanged.aspx) and raise the PropertyChanged event for `IsEqual` in the `Text1` and `Text2` PropertyChangedCallbacks.
3. Or, use a [MultiBinding](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.data.multibinding.aspx) in conjunction with a [IMultiValueConverter](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.data.imultivalueconverter.aspx) to bind the Background property directly to `Text1` and `Text2`. The converter would get two strings as input and return a Brush.

Comment: Yes, seems to be the simplest solution. Moreover, #1 would have to be a read-only dependency property.

Comment: First of all, thank you very much. I have a question about solution #2. I assume you say it is the UserControl itself that should implement INotifyPropertyChanged (I'm not sure anything else would make sense). However, as far as I can see, the PropertyChangedCallbacks for 'Text1' and 'Text2' are static ones... How is a static PropertyChangedCallback (the one you pass to PropertyMetadata when you register a DependencyProperty) supposed to raise a non-static INotifyPropertyChanged.PropertyChanged event?

Comment: If you look at the PropertyChangedCallback's signature you'll see that it gets a `DependencyObject` as first argument. This is your UserControl and can be casted to `INotifyPropertyChanged` if you implement that interface.

Comment: I see. I did read the documentation, but misinterpreted the meaning of that parameter. Thanks again for clarifying!

Answer (score 0):

You *can* debug UI in `` `WPF ``, even if it's not so straightorward as in usula `.NET` application. In your binding, only for debugging purposes, add a `Converter` for example. 
There are also other ways to ffigure out what is going on with `binding`.

Check out [Tips on how to debug and learn about WPF](http://joshsmithonwpf.wordpress.com/2007/03/29/tips-on-how-to-debug-and-learn-about-wpf/) excellent Josh Smith's article.

Using this, check out:

1. If your `Text1` and `Text2` properties get actually by the values you assign to them.
2. If there yes/no, there is some condition when it may no happen: for example you need to press `TAB` in order to loose focus, so run binding.

Checking at least this, you *should* already be able to come out with some ideas.

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

First of all, make sure that the object used as DataContext (with Password1 and Password2 properties) implements `INotifyPropertyChanged` interface for the properties.

To implement such a behavior, you can use [Dependency Property Callbacks and Validation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms745795.aspx): when the Text1 **or** Text2 property of the UserControl is changed, it is necessary to coerce (re-calculate) IsEqual property.

Here is the implementation:

```
public partial class CmpTextView : UserControl
{
    public CmpTextView()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    private static readonly DependencyPropertyKey IsEqualPropertyKey = DependencyProperty.RegisterReadOnly("IsEqual", typeof(bool), typeof(CmpTextView), new FrameworkPropertyMetadata(null, CoerceIsEqual));
    public static readonly DependencyProperty IsEqualProperty = IsEqualPropertyKey.DependencyProperty;

    public bool IsEqual
    {
        get { return (bool)GetValue(IsEqualProperty); }
    }

    private static object CoerceIsEqual(DependencyObject d, object baseValue)
    {
        CmpTextView cmpTextView = (CmpTextView) d;
        return cmpTextView.Text1 == cmpTextView.Text2;
    }

    public static readonly DependencyProperty Text1Property = DependencyProperty.Register("Text1", typeof(String), typeof(CmpTextView), new FrameworkPropertyMetadata(OnTextChanged));

    public string Text1
    {
        get { return (string)GetValue(Text1Property); }
        set { SetValue(Text1Property, value); }
    }

    public static readonly DependencyProperty Text2Property = DependencyProperty.Register("Text2", typeof(String), typeof(CmpTextView), new FrameworkPropertyMetadata(OnTextChanged));

    public string Text2
    {
        get { return (string)GetValue(Text2Property); }
        set { SetValue(Text2Property, value); }
    }

    private static void OnTextChanged(DependencyObject d, DependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        d.CoerceValue(IsEqualProperty);
    }
}
```

Hope it helps.

Comment: I think that property value coercion is a bit overdone here. It would be sufficient to make `IsEqual` a read-only dependency property by [RegisterReadOnly](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.dependencyproperty.registerreadonly.aspx) and then simply set it `OnTextChanged`.

Comment: @Clemens, thank you very much for pointing out to `RegisterReadOnly`! I've updated the code.
But I don't think that value coercion is an overdone here because value coercion has been designed to solve such problems. Just to clarify and refresh, value coercion is a mechanism to keep related (dependent from each other) dependency properties in sync and valid.

Comment: Well i know what value coercion was designed for, and i also know that it is unnecessary here. It would make a simple thing more complex without any additional benefit. There is never any need to coerce a read-only dependency property.